# Bind dynamically added input fields in Angular2

Tags: angular

I generate input fields in the template like this

```
 <input *ngFor="#number of numbers"  placeholder="Number"/>
```

in the component class

```
export class AppComp{
    public numbers : Array<number> = new Array(10);
}
```

I need to bind the dynamically added input values to the numbers array. I also need the place holder to read Number 1, Number 2 ... Number 10

Comment: The placeholder only shows when you don't have a value, so if you bind the values of each number in the array on each input you will not see the placeholder text. Do you mean you want to bind the values to a different array other than numbers?

Comment: Lets say, I have 3 input fields  and an array of length 3, I wan to bind each input field values to corresponding array element

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from this link https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-ng-for-syntax

```
 <input *ngFor="#number of numbers; #i = index" [(ngModel)]="numbers[i]"  placeholder="Number {{i}}" " />
```